# Why is this Groovy class static function not executed from its calling Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries

Directory structure of my Groovy shared library:

```
+- src                       # Groovy source files
|   +- org
|       +- company
|           +- Stage.groovy  # for org.company.Stage class
+- vars
    +- func.groovy           # for global var func()
```

The shared library is configured with name "foo" in the Jenkins Global Pipeline Libraries
[image]

The shared library files:

```
// src/org/company/Stage.groovy
package org.company;

class Stage  implements Serializable {
  static def func(d) {
    println("org.company.Stage.func()")
  }
}
```

```
// vars/func.groovy
def func(d) {
  println("func.groovy:func()")
}
```

In my pipeline's `Jenkinsfile`, I attempt to call both the global variable `func()` and the class static function `org.company.Stage.func()`:

```
// Jenkinsfile
pipeline {
  agent any

    stages {
      stage('1') {
        steps {
          testLoadLib()
        }
      }
    }
}

void testLoadLib() {
  loadLibrary('foo@dev')
}

void loadLibrary(String libraryName) {
  def lib = library(libraryName)
  def d = [:]
  func.func(d)
  lib.org.company.Stage.func(d)
}
```

The output (edited for relevance):

```
Loading library foo@dev
...
[Pipeline] echo
func.groovy:func()
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

The output appears to demonstrate that the global variable `def func()` is executed -- its `println()` appears in the console output.
But the class static function `org.company.Stage.func()` neither errors nor does its println appear in the console output.

**What's going on in this pipeline and its invocation of the shared library functions?

Why is only the global variable executed?

What do I need to to get the class function executed?**

The code above is based on the walkthrough at  http://rtyler.github.io/jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/ -- but I can't tell what I'm doing wrong vs. what's documented at that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a global variable method in general, `<groovy fiile name>.<method name>` (in your situation `func.func`) is indeed the correct syntax. However, to invoke a method from a shared library, you would first need to import the library and instantiate the class with a constructor:

```
import org.company.Stage
// one time constructor and method invocation
new Stage().func(d)
// assign constructor for efficiency if multiple method invocations
def stage = new Stage()
stage.func(d)
stage.func(foo)
```

In your usage the namespace syntax was incorrect, the `import` statemnet absent, and the class was being used as a singleton (which is not compatible with Jenkins Pipeline to my knowledge).

Alternatively you could also `import org.company.Stage.func` from the library, but then `func` would be defined by both the global variable method and the library, and this would likely cause issues.

You can view information about this in the "Accessing steps" section of the documentation you linked against in the question. Note the example in the documentation uses a custom constructor to enable definition and usage of `step` methods (specifically `sh` and `tool`) within that class in a clever albeit not entirely transparent manner.

Comment: The statement `def stage = new org.company.Stage()` for me results in the error `WorkflowScript: 22: unable to resolve class org.company.Stage` -- do you happen to know what this error is? What you explained makes sense to me...I'm now just stuck with this technical obstacle implementing it.

Comment: @StoneThrow I think I was mistaken about the `import` being unnecessary, and the documentation is missing some information due to assumptions. Updating answer.

Comment: Made the edits finally: by adding an explicit `@Library` statement and the `import` statement from your updated answer, I do not get a runtime error anymore, but the `println()` in the `org.company.Stage.func()` function still doesn't "execute" -- I don't see it in the console log. </puzzled>

Comment: This is interesting: I confirmed that the function itself is "executing" by making it return a value that I print in the invoking Jenkinsfile -- and that is functioning correctly. But the `println()` inside the shared library class function itself is "disappearing" -- it doesn't appear in the console log. This may be worth a separate question; in the meanwhile I am accepting your answer -- thank you.

Comment: @StoneThrow Then I believe the root cause for not observing a logged output to `stdout` would be unrelated to the method invocation (and perhaps your usage was even correct already), but rather related to method definition or something else i.e. flushing a buffer.

Comment: @StoneThrow Your last comment seems to confirm my theory. I have no idea if it is related to the `static` because I never use that in Groovy (and checking the documentation claims it is related to traits, and I only know traits in Rust), but maybe that is the root cause? I think it is probably related to Jenkins Pipeline logging behavior more than anything though.

Comment: For what it's worth, here's a new question, specific to the issue about the `println()` behavior in global variables versus class member functions -- perhaps you may have some insight there, as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76048769/what-doesnt-a-println-in-a-groovy-shared-library-class-member-function-appear