# What doesn't a println() in a Groovy shared library class member function appear in the Jenkins console log?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries

This question follows from [Why is this Groovy class static function not executed from its calling Jenkins pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76040495/why-is-this-groovy-class-static-function-not-executed-from-its-calling-jenkins-p).

I have a Jenkins/groovy shared library set up like this:

```
+- src                       # Groovy source files
|   +- org
|       +- company
|           +- Stage.groovy  # for org.company.Stage class
+- vars
    +- func.groovy           # for global var func()
```

The shared library is set up as a Global Pipeline Library named 'foo':
[image]

The shared library implements a global variable:

```
// vars/func.groovy
def func(d) {
  println("func.groovy:func()")
}
```

...and class `Stage` with member function `func`:

```
// src/org/company/Stage.groovy
package org.company;

class Stage  implements Serializable {
  def func(d) {
    println("org.company.Stage.func()")
    return 'hello, world!`
  }
}
```

Note that both the global variable and the class member function do the same thing: `println` of some static string.

My Jenkins pipeline calls both the global variable and the class member function:

```
// Jenkinsfile
@Library('foo@dev')
import org.company.Stage

pipeline {
  agent any

    stages {
      stage('1') {
        steps {
          testLoadLib()
        }
      }
    }
}

void testLoadLib() {
  loadLibrary('foo@dev')
}

void loadLibrary(String libraryName) {
  def lib = library(libraryName)
  def d = [:]
  func.func(d)

  def myvar = new Stage()
  def ret = myvar.func()
  println(ret)
}
```

The output of this Jenkins pipeline is:

```
Only using first definition of library foo
[Pipeline] echo
func.groovy:func()
[Pipeline] echo
hello, world!
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

**Question:** why is the `println()` in `org.company.Stage.func()` not reflected in the Jenkins console log whereas the `println()` in the global variable `func.func()` is reflected in the Jenkins console log?
By using the return-value from `org.company.Stage.func()`, it's clear that the function is being executed...but its functionality is "crippled" -- I don't know how else to describe it...the `println` is muted...what other functionality is compromised?
Why would the behavior of this `println()` statement be different between invoking a global variable versus invoking a class function?

I have tried various combinations of `class Stage` vs. `public class Stage`, `def func(d)` vs. `public def func(d)`, removing/keeping `implements Serializable`, and the `@NonCPS` annotation -- none of that appears to affect the behavior described above.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this by throwing spaghetti at the wall and seeing what stuck.

Starting with a Jenkinsfile like this:

```
// Jenkinsfile
@Library('foo@dev')
import org.company.Stage
...
def myvar = new Stage(steps)
myvar.func()
```

...this works:

```
// src/org/company/Stage.groovy
package org.company;

class Stage {
  def steps
  Stage(steps) {this.steps = steps}
  def func(d) {
    steps.echo("org.company.Stage.func()")
  }
}
```

This **does not** work:

```
// src/org/company/Stage.groovy
package org.company;

class Stage {
  def steps
  Stage(steps) {this.steps = steps}
  def func(d) {
    steps.println("org.company.Stage.func()")
  }
}
```

I.e. two things appear necessary as an answer to the question asked:

1. The shared library class must be given, and use, a handle to `steps`.
2. The shared library class must use `steps.echo`, and not `steps.println`.

Jenkins/Groovy continues to slowly drive me insane.

Comment: that was obvious ))